When using a shared value from react native reanimated, updating an unrelated state causes unexpected behaviour
After malding for 6 whole hours I finally have a minimal reproducible example of my logic-defying problem:
import "expo-dev-client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import Animated, { useSharedValue } from "react-native-reanimated";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(false);
  const toggleScreen = () => setA((p) => !p);
  if (a) return <Content toggleScreen={toggleScreen} />;
  else
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button title="next" onPress={toggleScreen} />
      </View>
    );
}

function Content({ toggleScreen }: { toggleScreen: () => void }) {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const sharedValue = useSharedValue(0);

  return (
    <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, paddingTop: 50 }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Button title="back" onPress={toggleScreen} />
        <Button
          title={`update state ${a}`}
          onPress={() => setA((p) => p + 1)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Animated.Text
          style={{ position: "absolute", borderWidth: 1, top: sharedValue }}
        >
          {`using shared value (${sharedValue.value})`}
        </Animated.Text>
        <Animated.Text style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0 }}>
          using absolute number
        </Animated.Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

When the "update state" button is pressed, the Animated.Text component that uses the shared value jumps to the centre of the parent component, as if the top property becomes ignored. This is even though the state object is completely unused, and the shared value is never changed. The borderWidth property remains in effect. Is this supposed to happen? I don't want it to happen. Am I doing something wrong? How do I make it not happen?
 

@ihsnktmr my code is literally right there. Is this a chatgpt response?

When you update a state in React, it triggers a re-render of the component and its children. This re-render might be affecting the layout of your Animated.Text components.
Solutions
Use useAnimatedStyle: Ensure you are using useAnimatedStyle to define the styles that depend on shared values. This hook ensures that the styles are correctly recalculated when the shared value changes.
Memoize Components: Use React.memo to memoize components that don't need to re-render when the state changes. This can prevent unnecessary re-renders and layout recalculations.
Separate Components: Split the Content component into smaller components to isolate the parts that depend on the shared value from the parts that depend on the state.
import "expo-dev-client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import Animated, { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle } from "react-native-reanimated";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(false);
  const toggleScreen = () => setA((p) => !p);
  if (a) return <Content toggleScreen={toggleScreen} />;
  else
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button title="next" onPress={toggleScreen} />
      </View>
    );
}

const Content = React.memo(({ toggleScreen }) => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);
  const sharedValue = useSharedValue(0);

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      top: sharedValue.value,
      borderWidth: 1,
    };
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, paddingTop: 50 }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Button title="back" onPress={toggleScreen} />
        <Button
          title={`update state ${a}`}
          onPress={() => setA((p) => p + 1)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Animated.Text style={[animatedStyle, { position: "absolute" }]}>
          {`using shared value (${sharedValue.value})`}
        </Animated.Text>
        <Animated.Text style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0 }}>
          using absolute number
        </Animated.Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});

export default App;


looks like another chatgpt response
